# A question about Tarski Monster Group

Tags: group-theory

Let $\alpha$ be a cardinality. Is there a Tarski moster group with exacly $\alpha$ non-trivial proper subgroups‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌?

**Edit**: I found it interesting to know if there is such generalization for tarski group.

Comment: As the close reason requests, please improve the question by providing additional context.  Your Readers will benefit from your own thoughts about an approach, definitions of terms, etc.

Comment: @hardmath: As is clear it is just an interesting question. A complete, understandable mathematical question. Requesting for a yes/no answer. Really I have nothing else to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Since those groups are finitely generated, they are countable. Since each proper nontrivial subgroup if generated by one of its $p-1$ element, and different proper subgroup disjoint except at the identity, the number of non-trivial proper subgroup must be $\aleph_{0}$.

Comment: @user138171:Take any 2 noncommuting element, and consider the subgroup generate by them. It is not a cyclic subgroup, hence must be the whole group itself.

Comment: yep‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌. that was clear!